# Mostrar ñ y signos de acentuación en etiquetas <pre> en HTML

Tags: php, html5

Estoy haciendo una página de internet en donde no tengo problemas con los caracteres en español como pueden ver:

[image: mostrando la ñ]

Para eso utilizo esto en HTML:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Pero tengo unas etiquetas `<pre>` en donde salen archivos de texto que yo leo del servidor pero éstas no me respetan los caracteres en español:

[image: Mostrar letra]

Comment: Esa info sale de una base de datos?

Comment: no de archivos .txt

Comment: En el txt aparece la ñ?

Comment: A la hora de leer el archivo tienes que indicarle su codificación o convertirlo

Comment: si si tiene la letra ñ y como es que especifico la codificación del archivo

Comment: Prueba a usar la función htmlentities cuando insertes el texto leído dentro de la etiqueta PRE

Comment: ¿Qué editor de textos has usado para crear los scripts PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El símbolo � (carácter de reemplazo) aparece en documentos UTF-8 en los que el carácter no puede ser interpretado, probablemente por tratarse de un carácter ISO-8859-xx.

Si quieres trabajar con utf-8 en todos los niveles, debes hacerlo siguiendo los siguientes pasos:

- Tu servidor debe devolver la cabecera `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` ya sea generada desde el propio script PHP (con [`header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8')`](http://php.net/header)) o desde el servidor web ([`AddType`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) o [`AddCharset`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addcharset) en la configuración de apache, por ejemplo).
- Las locales de PHP también deben soportar `UTF-8`. Casi todos los sistemas Linux modernos tienen por defecto `en_US.UTF-8` o `es_ES.UTF-8` o equivalente. Si el que viene configurado por defecto es diferente deberás cambiarlo con [`setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES.UTF-8')`](http://php.net/setlocale). Usa `locale -a` para obtener el listado disponible.
- Tu HTML debe tener definido el juego de caracteres usando la etiqueta `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` en compatibilidad con HTML4 y/o `<meta charset="utf-8">` usando HTML5.
- Tu editor de textos debe soportar UTF-8 para que los textos que introduzcas en los scripts PHP estén correctamente codificados.

Tanto el formulario de solicitud de usuario/contraseña como el que muestra el resultado (el que te da problemas) deben cumplir esos requisitos para no darte ningún tipo de problema con juegos de caracteres.

Tu problema podría tratarse de:

- Has creado un documento con las etiquetas HTML correctas, se envían las cabeceras HTTP correctas, pero el editor que has usado ha creado un archivo PHP de recepción con codificación ISO en vez de UTF. La solución pasa por abrir el archivo que recibe el formulario y buscar la opción de tu editor para guardarlo en UTF-8.
- Las cabeceras o codificación del formulario de origen están bien (UTF), pero la página que recibe los datos no. La solución pasa por poner al mismo nivel cabeceras y etiquetas para igualar la codificación.

Dado que tu texto parece estático, programado en el script de manera fija, me decanto con la primera opción.

Comment: pues el archivo que leo desde PHP lo creo en un bloc de notas, como puedo cambiar su codificacion

Comment: El bloc de notas creo que no soporta nada más que ISO (quizá en la opción de guardar como.. pero no lo puedo comprobar en mi equipo), así que ese es el problema. Puedes, como solución temporal, sustituir la `ñ` por `&ntilde;`, pero deberás cambiar a un editor de texto que te permita elegir el juego de caracteres. Te recomiendo [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.5.8.html).

Comment: Muchimas gracias amigo ya pude encontrar donde cambiar la codificacion...

Comment: De nada :) ¿cómo lo hiciste? (lo siento, soy usuario de ubuntu, no tengo el bloc de notas para probar). Te recomiendo usar Notepad++ como te puse en el comentario anterior, o bien Atom o incluso Visual Studio Code.

Comment: abrí el bloc de notas me voy a archivo, guardar como, y en donde viene como lo quieres guardar y de que extension abajo viene un lista desplegable que dice codificacion y por defecto para mi estaba ANSI y lo cambie a UTF--8

Answer (score 0):

podrias probar a utilizar `utf8_encode()` para codificar en utf8 el texto extraido de los files, ejemplo:

```
$codificado = utf8_encode(texto);
```

espero que te sea de ayuda